# promise with two async function in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

context :

i need to call a function (function A) to make HTTP request two time, after this, i need to call another fonction (function B) that compute the two array

the normal order should be

- (Function A & Function A) asynchronously
- when the 2 other are done, Function B

so i turned myself to promise, but here is the issue, i can't figured out how to syntax it properly, i use Coffeescript.

here's what i got so far, but right now it's not working

```
myCoolPromise = () ->
  return new Promise (resolve, reject) ->
  postRequest(diagUrl, diagnosisBody, storesConnectionObject)
  postRequest(storesUrl, brandBody, storesObject)
  success = true
  if success
    resolve 'stuff worked'
  else
    reject Error 'it broke'


myCoolPromise(storesObject.storesArray, storesConnectionObject.storesArray, absentObject).then (response) ->
  console.log 'success', response
  handleResult(storesObject.storesArray, storesConnectionObject.storesArray, absentObject)
.catch (error) ->
  console.error 'failed', error
```

Comment: I don't get what `myCoolPromise` is supposed to do. It doesn't seem to be asynchronous at all, and `success` is always true, so you shouldn't use promises here?

Answer (score 0):

i answer my own question to keep a trace in StackOverflow

my problem was syntax side

i changed `postRequest` to return a promise, resolve if the request get back with statuscode 200 or reject if error, and chained the two function in a promise like this :

```
  myCoolPromise = (diagUrl, diagnosisBody, storesUrl, brandBody) ->
    return new Promise (resolve, reject) ->
      postRequest(diagUrl, diagnosisBody)
        .then (storesConnectionObject) ->
          postRequest(storesUrl, brandBody)
            .then (storesObject) ->
              resolve handleResult(storesObject, storesConnectionObject)
            .catch (error1) ->
              reject error1
        .catch (error2) ->
          reject error2
```

i'm still open to a better way to resolve this, thanks

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: Just `return Promise.all(postRequest(…), postRequest(…)].then(handleResult)`?

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of issues with this code, so I'll just go one by one.

First of all, you're using this code to invoke the function:

```
myCoolPromise(storesObject.storesArray, storesConnectionObject.storesArray, absentObject).then (response) ->
```

In order for this to work, your `myCoolPromise` method would need to take 3 arguments (right now it takes 0).

Second, in Coffeescript the indentation after the `new Promise` line is absolutely necessary. Right now you have this:

```
  return new Promise (resolve, reject) ->
  postRequest(diagUrl, diagnosisBody, storesConnectionObject)
```

Because the following lines aren't indented, anything after that first line is *not* considered part of the promise, and your `myCoolPromise` method returns an empty promise.

Now finally, onto the content of the promise (the async call itself). You haven't shown how `postRequest` is defined, but the way you're calling it, it does not seem to be async. Keep in mind that, besides ES7 `await`, promises, and cpu-hogging loops, the only way Javascript supports async is calbacks. So, if `postRequest` has a callback api, you supply a callback with the incovation and inside the callback body, invoke the `resolve` or `reject`. On the other hand, if `postRequest` offers a promise api, you can chain on `.then -> resolve("success")` and such

Comment: my `postRequest` function is structured like this 


`postRequest =(postUrl, postBody, postArray) ->`


i don't understand why `handleresult` is still trigger first 
now, the 3 function are invoked but in the same order than without promise, and console.log 'stuff worked' are not shown for exemple